# Enclosing place: publication in parentheses

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

Using biblatex and author-date styles, how do I go about customising my bibliography so that place/address: publisher becomes (address: publisher) e.g. (London: Routledge) rather than London: Routledge.

Similarly how do I customise vol and no in a periodical to read vol:no?

There is no style file for the (Blackwell) journal I wish to submit to and my old BST file made in makebst no longer works with biblatex/biber.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{publisher+location+date}{%
  \printtext[parens]{% ADDED
    \printlist{location}%
    \iflistundef{publisher}
      {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
      {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
    \printlist{publisher}%
    \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
  }\nopunct% ADDED
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
%  \setunit*{\adddot}% DELETED
  \setunit*{\addcolon}% ADDED
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{knuth:ct:a,shore}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

See also [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles).